# set color scaling of a vector in R

Tags: r, colors

I would like to take a vector of numerical values between 0 and 1 over a color scale of my choice. Right now I can get control when there are two colors with the code below.

```
library(plotrix)
set.seed(1)
x <- sort(runif(10, min = 0, max = 1))
redsNblues<- color.scale(x, extremes = c("#ff0000", "#0000ff"))
plot(x, col = redsNblues)
```

But how would I do this elegantly if I wanted to go from blue to red with white in between?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(plotrix)
set.seed(1)
x <- sort(runif(10, min = 0, max = 1))

# Create a color function that will return colors in the range we want
colorfunc = colorRamp(c("blue","white","red"))

# Use colorfunc to create colors that range from blue to white to red 
# across the range of x
mycolors = rgb(colorfunc(x), maxColorValue=255)

plot(x, col=mycolors, pch=16, cex=3)
```

[image]